# MySQL Error 1415

Tags: mysql, function, variables, select, declare

I'm currently coding somewhat on MySQL and got a FUNCTION.
For me the code looks fine, but MySQL throws a

`Error Code: 1415
Not allowed to return a result set from a function`
Error.

Function:
[Cick here, pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/Pz9NFRGD)

As i said, i dont see any syntax error in it and simply cant understand why its throwing an Error. Only on execution though, creates without any problems.

I googled already, and haven't found anything helping my on this, so i hope you can. 
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced all the other functions referenced in your new function with ROUND(RAND()) and it ran fine; Could it be that one of those functions might be trying to return a result set?

Comment: The functions run fine if i try them out one per one.. And i checked them and they don't try to return a result set :<

Comment: well it, if i remove the MacAllowed-statement it works. If i try the MacAllowed function in a simple select query, it works too...  >.>

Comment: well i found it but it was in a procedure o,o